# Models merge in RTC

Tags: model, rtc

I have 2 version IDs of the same Model file in RTC which are required to be merged into the latest one.

Version ID - 1: 500 created/updated on 2nd Apr, 2018

Version ID - 2: 590 created/updated on 9th Apr, 2018

I want to auto merge them into the latest file, can that be done in RTC.

Note: The stream is the same.